# Does fingering count as sexual intercourse?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, non-mahram

I have done "premarital sex" with my boyfriend using with fingers only. No other sexual relation has occurred. Is it considered that I have done sexual intercourse? What are the rules in Islam?

Answer (score 3):

What you did is considered minor sin. In Islam Adultery happens when a penis penetrates the Vagina.

There is no punishment for such actions in Islam, which are forgiven by doing your daily Salah and asking Allah for forgiveness.

There is a similar [hadith](http://sunnah.com/urn/1314630) about the prophet PBUH for your situation:

> It was narrated from ‘Abdullah bin Mas’ud that a man did something with a woman that was less than adultery; I do not know how far it went, but it was less than adultery. He went to the Prophet (ﷺ) and told him about that. Then Allah revealed the words:
>   “And perform the prayer, at the two ends of the day and in some hours of the night. Verily, the good deeds remove the evil deeds. That is a reminder for the mindful.” [11:114] He said: “O Messenger of Allah, is this only for me?” He said: “It is for everyone who acts upon it.”

Don't get me wrong, what you did is still considered Zina, but the type of Zina that does not come with Punishment (looking at porn, Lesbianism, masturbating, etc..) and erased by asking for forgiveness.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular case, I think I can put forward this verse,

> And tell the believing women to **lower their gaze** (from looking at forbidden things), and protect their private parts (from illegal sexual acts, etc.) and not to show off their adornment except only that which is apparent (like palms of hands or one eye or both eyes for necessity to see the way, or outer dress like veil, gloves, head-cover, apron, etc.), and to draw their veils all over Juyubihinna (i.e. their bodies, faces, necks and bosoms, etc.) and not to reveal their adornment except to their husbands.... (Qur'an 24:31)

Whether what you did was sex or not, first of you should not put forth your question directly putting yourself in your question, but you should ask for the general ruling. Now to your case, as a community, the people would simply charge you with Qur'an 24:2. Otherwise, you need to repent from the bottom of your heart. Rest, plz follow typod's answer.

> Is the alllah then never forgive me?

That is Allah's wish. He may forgive according to ....

> Allah accepts only the repentance of those who do evil in ignorance and foolishness and repent soon afterwards; it is they to whom Allah will forgive and Allah is Ever All-Knower, All-Wise. (Qur'an 4:17)

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is Haram,
You should truly repent on what you did.
Boy - Girlfriend relation is not allowed.
Every single human being may not touch anyone from the opposite side.
Only his/her husband/wife, and this is done after marriage.

Allah tells us to not even come near zina,

Using your finger is still sexual, if we may not touch each other, why would sexually pleasure(zina) someone be allowed? Coming near it is already bad, Isn't the thing you've done even worse?

People who commit adultery (married people)were stoned to death,unmarried people will get the punishment of 100 lashes, you're lucky this isn't your case and this means you can repent.
(you are not being stoned or getting lashes, which means you have time to better yourself without punishment and ask Allah for forgiveness before death takes you away)

Allah is the most merciful, if this was a mistake then he will forgive you because it wasn't your intention to do so.
If you did this knowing this is Haram then you did a big sin, repent to Allah and do good deeds so that he may forgive you.

for clarification for the punishment:

> “The fornicatress and the fornicator, flog each of them with a hundred stripes. Let not pity withhold you in their case, in a punishment prescribed by Allaah, if you believe in Allaah and the Last Day. And let a party of the believers witness their punishment”

[al-Noor 24:2] (Quran)

the case if someone is married:

> It was narrated from Jaabir that a man from (the tribe of) Aslam came to the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) when he was in the mosque and he said, “I have committed adultery.”  The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) turned his face away from him. The man came to that side to which the Prophet had turned his face, and testified against himself four times. The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said, "Are you mad?” He said, “No.” The Prophet said, “Are you married?" He said, "Yes.” So he commanded that he be stoned in the Musalla (Eid prayer place). When the stones troubled him, he ran away, until he was caught in al-Harrah and killed.

source: [islamqa.info](http://islamqa.info/en/8980)

Allah knows best,

Comment: I meant with it that she is lucky that she isn't currently stoned to death, which means she has time to repent and better herself.

Comment: i've edited my answer as clarification, thanks for letting me revising it. If there is still anything else, i would like to hear it. and btw. touching someone sexually is like zina, so in this case the punishment would be the same,

Comment: In all the classic fiqh books zina is defined as genital intercourse; there is no way that finger sex can be defined as zina. I am not denying that the latter is a sin according to Islam, but it is not zina and thus not punishable by stoning.

Comment: She may not have had "normal" sex, however instead of the penis fingers were used, not her own fingers. But still there was a penetration, which counts as zina. Zina can come in every form, not just sex, looking, touching also comes in the category zina to the eyes and hands. Looking may have another effect (masturbation comes in an other category). The Prophet once said: “The eyes commit Zina, the hands commit Zina and feet commit Zina and the genitals commit Zina.” (Musnad Ahmad, Hadith no. 4258) even if it way not come under the category of it, the feeling (psychical/mentally) is the same

Comment: Please stop making your own rules. The Had on zina is when there are 4 witnesses to the penis penetrating the vagina, this is agreed by ALL scholars including Sunni/Shia. There is Zina with Had (sexual intercourse/penetration) and Zina without Had, like Lesbianism, etc..